# CRUD for the sql lite for windows 8 metro application

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I did a lot of research on the CRUD for the SQLlite for the windows 8 metro application but i didn't find anything useful, I just want some simple CRUD syntax for the SQLlite application and I also want to get the last row inserted id

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx) of how to do simple INSERTs in a Store style app with SQLite.  You can use the [Last Insert Rowid function](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) to get the id of the row you use inserted.  Given you have the setup in the example, something like ...

```
db.runAsync('INSERT INTO ...');  // whatever your insert statement is    
db.runAsync('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ROWID()');
```